# RH Develoiper Studio to JBoss EAP server connection

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7, jboss-developer-studio

I have tried Developer Studio 11.3.0, and 12.0.0.  I've tried EAP 6.4.0, and 7.1.0.  Everything gives me the same error.  I've run it with servers in RHEL on AWS and a DevStudio in Windows 10 or Windows 7.  I've run it with server and DevStudio on the same Fedora system.  Always the same error when I try to "start" the remote server:

```
The initialization produced an exception, which can occur due to incorrect security credentials. Please review the exception messages by clicking the Details button.
 * java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://LOCALHOST:9990. The connection failed
 * java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://LOCALHOST:9990. The connection failed
 * WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://LOCALHOST:9990. The connection failed
 * Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
   JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05128: [JBOSS-LOCAL-USER] Failed to read challenge file [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: /datavirt/jboss/EAP-7.1.0/standalone/tmp/auth/local3848441195962286340.challenge (Permission denied)]
   DIGEST-MD5: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: Server rejected authentication
```

Here's a bit of the server.log file, where things go wrong.  (It's slightly different in 6.4.0, but not substantially.)

```
2018-09-01 23:20:52,946 TRACE [org.jboss.remoting.endpoint] (management I/O-2) Allocated tick to 8 of endpoint "miramanee:MANAGEMENT" <68fb9f51> (opened org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor@18776914)
2018-09-01 23:20:52,946 TRACE [org.xnio.nio] (management I/O-2) Running task org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ServerConnectionOpenListener$2@228e4439
2018-09-01 23:20:52,946 TRACE [org.xnio.nio.selector] (management I/O-2) Beginning select on sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@617c6bff (with timeout)
2018-09-01 23:20:52,946 TRACE [org.xnio.nio] (management I/O-2) Select, queue is empty
2018-09-01 23:20:52,946 TRACE [org.wildfly.security] (management task-7) Handling RealmCallback: selected = [ManagementRealm]
2018-09-01 23:20:52,946 TRACE [org.wildfly.security] (management task-7) Handling NameCallback: authenticationName = admin
2018-09-01 23:20:52,946 TRACE [org.wildfly.security] (management task-7) Principal assigning: [admin], pre-realm rewritten: [admin@ManagementRealm], realm name: [DIGEST], post-realm rewritten: [admin@ManagementRealm], realm rewritten: [admin@ManagementRealm]
2018-09-01 23:20:52,947 TRACE [org.wildfly.security] (management task-7) Handling CredentialCallback: obtained credential for correct realm "ManagementRealm"
2018-09-01 23:20:52,947 TRACE [org.wildfly.security] (management task-7) Handling CredentialCallback: obtained credential: org.wildfly.security.credential.PasswordCredential@b75f36fa
2018-09-01 23:20:52,947 TRACE [org.jboss.remoting.remote.server] (management task-7) Server sending authentication rejected: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05055: [DIGEST-MD5] Authentication rejected (invalid proof)
        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.digest.DigestSaslServer.validateDigestResponse(DigestSaslServer.java:281)
        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.digest.DigestSaslServer.evaluateMessage(DigestSaslServer.java:358)
        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractSaslParticipant.evaluateMessage(AbstractSaslParticipant.java:180)
        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.digest.DigestSaslServer.evaluateResponse(DigestSaslServer.java:331)
        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AuthenticationCompleteCallbackSaslServerFactory$1.evaluateResponse(AuthenticationCompleteCallbackSaslServerFactory.java:58)
        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AuthenticationTimeoutSaslServerFactory$DelegatingTimeoutSaslServer.evaluateResponse(AuthenticationTimeoutSaslServerFactory.java:106)
```

I am plumb stumped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it going quickly for learning/etc, then I can just say what I'm doing. I have RHEL 7 & EAP 7.1. I'm using dev studio 12 on same machine. When I added a server into dev studio, I had option to select local or remote. I selected local and had no problems starting via dev studio. The user I'm running dev studio with also has permissions to EAP home directory (I see file perm errors in your error). I also chose management options vs. Filesystem and shell operations. I also test, and this worked picking remote as well. But again, same server for everything/same localhost.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that.  But no, this is work, and remote systems.